How to protect sensitive data in Azure?
I would like to load sensitive data in an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. I need to make sure that this data can not be read by the global administrator or any other kind of super user. How can this be realized?
I think role-based access control is not really sufficient for this. I was thinking about access control lists (ACL) but how can you make sure that the global administrator can not just change the ACLs again?
But maybe this is the completely wrong approach. If you have any idea on how to realize this I would very much appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Take a look on Azure Pureview. You will mark which data is considered sensitive, then create and assign roles in Microsoft Entra (former Azure AD) to proper allow/restrict access to the data.
